# How do I parse the free format address to save into the DataBase

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text area that allow user the type in an address in free format, how do I parse the address user entered into address1, address2, city, state, zip and country and save into DB?

Answer (score 2):

You are in for a lot of pain here.

Addresses REALLY BADLY differ between countries, and even within one country parsing is error prone. Been there, leading a team of 2 people spending months trying to get all GERMAN addresses to parse. Lots of stupid little specialties left and right.

Sad news - I dont think that can be done reliably. Not oif the entry is free form, not with the way people enter addresses in various ways.

Go with a decent entry form, not with free text entry.

Answer (score 1):

Don't, go with a separate-field data entry form instead.

Assuming you don't/can't/won't heed that advice, then you have to make some assumptions about how it's been entered.  You can be a little clever by start from the ends and work your way in, though.

I.e:

- Split by new lines.
- 1st line is housenumber and street.
- Last line could be postcode/zipcode.
- Last-but-one line could be city.
- Lines in-between first and last-but-one are address line 2, 3 etc.

**IMPORTANT**
Address formats vary wildly between countries.  If I were you and you have the scope for it, I'd **at least** provide a country drop-down so you can apply different parsing rules for each country.

Answer (score 0):

You can't predict how a user is going to enter the address e.g. some prefer using newlines, others prefer using comma's.

To save the hassle I would just have separate fields for each individual item, or just save the address as a whole string.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you will be able to parse it correctly in case of free format. You may use [MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) for these purposes. Another way is to require user to enter information in certain order.